# Program crashes when executed remotly, but not locally

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to run this program https://github.com/spirit-code/spirit. After setting it up with Qt & Qt charts 5.7 it works nicely and I can start it without any problems.

Then I tried to start it remotely through ssh -Y it works nicely until this step:

```
2016-11-19 14:58:08  [ INFO  ] [UI  ] [--] [--]  QSurfaceFormat version: 3.3
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

The last line is just German for segmentation fault. Why would a program run nicely locally, but crash on remote execution?

Comment: Probably because it has undefined behaviour in it, which means the fact that it works locally is just a random coincidence. Your first job is to find out which line causes the crash, then work your way back until you come up with an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

As the output suggests the program requires OpenGL to do part of its displaying operations.

That won't work through SSH's X11 forwarding